# ogrinfo - specify what information you want returned

Tags: gdal, shapefile, ogrinfo

I am using ogrinfo to find out information about a shapefile

```
ogrinfo -so -al 'C:/test/test_shapefile.shp'
```

This obviously gives me a large summary, but I'm wondering is there any way to specify that I only want information regarding the `extents` or `epsg` for example?

Comment: possibly if you return the output as a dict: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64424936/how-to-return-a-dictionary-as-a-functions-return-value-running-as-a-subprocess

Answer (score 3):

The ogr2ogr utility is a general purpose tool and all that it can do is documented in https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html. There are some options for limiting the amount of output (`-nocount` `-noextent` `nogeomtype`) but their main purpose is to make ogrinfo faster because with some formats getting such information may require reading every single feature from the source data.

Information that fits on one line and has a unique keyword can be filtered from the output with sed of find

```
ogrinfo -so -al test.shp|find "Extent"
Extent: (7156409.373471, 207.123904) - (7156409.373471, 207.123904)
```

Python scripting is probably the best option for getting just the desired information. There is a Python version of ogrinfo in the section of Python demos in GitHub https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/ogrinfo.py. It might be a good starting point for an own custom script.

Comment: ```ogrinfo -so -al test.shp|find "Extent"``` doesn't appear to work for me in the command-line. It doesn't return an error, just nothing

Comment: I've also had a look at the python version, but I can't make out where to specify my path to the shapefile

Comment: It is the first argument, just like with the ogrinfo executable `python ogrinfo.py c:\data\test.shp`

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be being silly, but I can't get it to work

Comment: Works for me. I tested on Windows with GDAL 3.4.1 and Python 3.9.5 installed with the OSGeo4W installer and with the script from the github link above. What is the error that you get?

Comment: I get the usage statement printed firstly, so I change the argv to be ```ogrinfo -so - al 'C:/test/test_shapefile.shp' but I get the error ```NameError: name 'ogrinfo' is not defined```

Comment: Please try to be clear, I do not quite get what you are doing. First: Are you on Windows? Second, about the `|find "Extent"` printing nothing, does `ogrinfo -so -al test.shp` print something? Does the output contain a line with "Extent". And third, did you try the ogrinfo literally as I did `python ogrinfo.py path_to_your_shape.shp`?

Comment: If you're getting a `NameError`, you tried to run ogrinfo.py from a python prompt instead of a command line.